# Is $ f(x) = {x \over x} $ well-defined at $x = 0$?

Tags: functions

Suppose that f is a function which domain and range are real numbers.

Then, If $ f(x) = {x \over x} $ then **Is f well-defined at** $x = 0$?

In other words, does ${x \over x} = 1$ equal on $ \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, but this is something called a removable discontinuity.

Answer (score 3):

No, because $f(0)=\frac{0}{0}$. However, because this function has a limit at $0$ (and everywhere else), you can make a continuous, well-defined function from it given by $\tilde{f}(x)=\lim\limits_{y\to x}f(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Not. However, you have some options:

1. You can restrict the domain to $ \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.
2. You can redefine a function $\tilde {f}$ by

$$
\tilde {f}(x)=  
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if} & x\neq0,\\
1 & \text{if} & x=0.\\
\end{cases}
$$